# Oracle SQL, one big table categorize columns and percentage distribution

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

I have one big mat view and in that, I want to categorize column A. For this column A I need the percentage distribution of column B.
Column A is a string value, column B is a number (length of something). Furthermore, I need only active values for this operation of column C (WHERE column_C = 'active') and I need another category of column D, which represents the specific kind of the values in column B (WHERE column_D IN ("kind_1", kind_2")).

So far I have this which only categorizes column A and counts column B and the percentage.

```
SELECT column_A, COUNT(*) AS column_A_count, (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table_matview WHERE column_D IN ('kind_1', 'kind_2')) * 100 AS Percentage1
FROM schema.table_matview 
WHERE column_D IN ('kind_1', 'kind_2')
GROUP BY column_A;
```

How it should look like:

```
column_A_categorized  |column_B_percentage_to_column_A_kindA  |
_____________________ |_______________________________        |
category_A            |13.4%                                  |
_____________________ |_______________________________        |
category_B            |6.9%                                   |
_____________________ |_______________________________        |
category_C            |60.1%                                  |
_____________________ |_______________________________        |
category_D            |19,6%                                  |
_____________________ |_______________________________        |
```

the same in the second column for kind_B but it didn't fit next to it
, so the third column is column_B_percentage_to_column_A_kindB.

```
column A has values like: Paris, Lyon, Nancy, Marseilles, Bordeaux
column B : (length of streets)
441
107015762
3254
3255
102953236
162
116
1252
1252
3
1824
5513
736
136
3
136
3554
6
482
731
72
6531
3252


column C: active, not active

column D: streettype like road/way/street/motorway/footway
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added some values and the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you need plain *Conditional Aggregation*:

```
SELECT column_A

   --  length of all streets passing the WHERE-condition
  ,sum(column_B) AS all_street_length

  ,sum(case when column_D = 'highway'  then column_B end) as highway_length
  ,sum(case when column_D = 'motorway' then column_B end) as motorway_length

  ,sum(case when column_D = 'highway'  then column_B end)
   / sum(column_B) * 100 AS highway_percentage

  ,sum(case when column_D = 'motorway' then column_B end)
   / sum(column_B) * 100 AS motorway_percentage
FROM schema.table_matview 
WHERE column_C = 'active' -- street is still drivable
  -- AND column_D IN ('highway', 'motorway')
GROUP BY column_A;
```

This returns the percentage based on *all* streets, not only highway/motorway (highway_percentage + motorway_percentage is (way) less than 100%). If you uncomment the `AND column_D IN ('highway', 'motorway')` it's based on those streets only (highway_percentage + motorway_percentage add up to exactly 100%)

Comment: Ok thank you @dnoeth, the results make more sense now. But I still don't know how to integrate the other category in the SQL Query. I provided some example values and how it should look in the end

Comment: @Anna. . . . This appears to answer your question.  If you have a different question, you should ask a new question rather than modifying this one -- and potentially invalidating the answer.

Comment: @dnoeth my question didn't change, I just provided information that GMB wanted. I initially needed the second category. Do you know how I could include the category from column D too?

Comment: Gordon likes new questions because he likes getting reputation :-) I don't understand your requirements, they're confusing, it's probably some kind of *conditional aggregation*: `SUM(sum(case when column_D = 'kind_1' then 1 else 0 end) OVER ()` and similar for kind_2? Or adding `PARTITON BY column_D`. Can you add more details, i.e. data and expected result?

Comment: @dnoeth, maybe I can explain it better with actual examples: I have a table with all the information about streets in cities. There is the calculated length of a street (column B)t, whether the street is still drivable (column C) and what kind of street it is (column D). All the streets belong to a city (column A). I want the following output:  For every city as category I need the percentage distribution of street lengths but only for highway streets and motorway streets. So the distribution has to be divided in the kind of street also. So in the result three columns: city, %kind_a & %kind_b